# how to backout to an older version ignoring all versions after that

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I have 3 commits which I pushed to the public repository accidentally. I want to revert to an older version (a version before these 3 commits happened) and make it the current code in our public repository.
I am using **TortoiseHg,version 2.11.1**

Comment: Hey Ajay.. is this what you want -> https://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/StripExtension

Comment: Stripping removed the selected commits from local, but the problem is the same exists in my public repository, having said that also when I try to get the latest changes the stripped changes also comes from the public repository

Comment: If you have access to the central, you could strip it, but if someone else has already pulled your changes, then they would re-appear in the central again the next time they push. I think you should inform your team members to not make any change till you complete the strip command in the central. Once it is done, ask everyone to reclone.

Comment: I think, that will work, but I do not have access to the central. However I achieved the same functionality by backing the 3 unintended commits. So in effect the code that I have currently as the current version is the intended version.  Could you post your comment as answer because I think strip would be the cleanest option provided central repo is accessible.

Comment: Does your unintended commits include binary files?

Comment: It does not but instead its a merge from another barch

Comment: @ajay, I'm not sure stripping is the cleanest option. Note that others might have already pulled the changes and it won't work well in such case.

Comment: @geckon Then what about the option of backing out the changes until I reach the intended commit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1**

You can use the strip option as mentioned in the command
hg strip  is the command
This extension has to be enabled
Enable the extension by adding the following lines to your .hgrc or Mercurial.ini:
[extensions]
strip =
This option is only suitable if you have access to the central repository where your code is hosted and you have a small group in which you would know if someone have already pulled your changes.

**Option 2**

Another option would be to backout these 3 commits, Since you are using UI,I will attach a screen shot

Step 1: Right click the unwanted commit and you will see a backout option click that and the wizard wll guide you.
if its a merge that you are trying to backout then you have to select which branch to backout to.

Do the same for the 3 unwanted commits

[image]

**Option 3**

if you have many commits and if its in a named branch following these steps will provide a solution

1) Close the branch and update to the last good commit you want.
2) Reopen the barch from there by new commit (Named branch can have multiple heads)
3) use hg revert -r  and commit

This will make the working directory exactly as the last good commit you need and ignore the inwanted commits. This will only work if the commits are in a named branch.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
hg backout -r <rev>
hg push
```

This will backout to the `<rev>` revision (which should be the last correct commit). In other words, it will set your working directory into the same state as it was on the last correct commit and create a new commit with an explanatory message. Then you'll push it to the public repository so it's the current code again.

Comment: I usually do through UI, but as far as I  understand this will update my local code version to the revision that I intend to but doesn't create a new revision. I tried this to yield no result, when I try to commit I am getting a message saying nothing changed.

Comment: My answer contains three commands. The first one updates your local code, the second one creates a new revision and the third one pushes the new revision to the remote repository.

Comment: But the when I try the second one instead of creating a new commit it shows the message "nothing changed"

Comment: @ajay, sorry, my bad. I edited the answer. This should work :)

Comment: This removes the changes that I had done in that commit. Also before push command, shouldnt we do a hg commit

Comment: `hg backout` should create the commit itself. Check your `hg log` after `hg backout`.